# best way for finding approximate root of monotonic sawtooth like function

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

First I will generate such kind of monotonic sawtooth like function called `func`

```
n = 50;
block = Symmetrize[RandomReal[1., {n, n}], Symmetric[{1, 2}]];
diagF = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> Normal /@ #] &;
mat = diagF[{block, block, block, block}];
dim = Length@mat;
eigs = Transpose@Sort@Transpose@Eigensystem@mat;
eigsdensity = {eigs[[1]], Abs[eigs[[2]]]^2};
fermiCom = 
  Compile[{{e, _Real}, {u, _Real}, {t, _Real}}, 
   Module[{tmp}, tmp = Exp[(u - e)/t]; tmp = 1./(1. + tmp); 
    tmp = 1. - tmp], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
Clear[fermi];
fermi[e_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := fermiCom[e, u, t];
num = Length@Select[eigs[[1]], # < 0 &] + 1;
Clear[func];
func[u_] := 
 Total[Sum[
   eigsdensity[[2, i]] fermi[eigs[[1, i]], u, 0.0001], {i, 1, dim}]]
```

The plot of `func` is like this

```
Plot[func[u], {u, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

This is what I call monomotic sawtooth like function

Now I want to know **at which `u` value, `func[u]` is closest to `num` ( `num = Length@Select[eigs[[1]], # < 0 &] + 1`)**

Normally, `FindRoot` fastest for this kind of task. However it is not working for this problem

```
FindRoot[func[u] - num == 0, {u, 0}]
```

gives error

> FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {u} =
>   {0.}. Try perturbing the initial point(s). >>

This is because `num` is a value guaranteed to be between two plateaus (the `fermi` function is very close to step function, while not exactly the same), so it can't find such a root.

Then, we can transform the problem into a minimization problem. That is to minimize `Abs[func[u] - num]`

However`FindMinimum` is also not working.

```
FindMinimum[Abs[func[u] - num], u]
```

> FindMinimum::fmgz: Encountered a gradient that is effectively zero.
>   The result returned may not be a minimum; it may be a maximum or a
>   saddle point. >>

The only working, I know at the moment is `NMinimize`

```
NMinimize[Abs[func[u] - num], u] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.934564, {1., {u -> 0.0116856}}}*)
```

**But as you can see `NMinimize` is really expensive. So I wonder, since the `func` such a good monotonic property, is there a better way than direct `NMinimize`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`FindRoot` documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html):

> `FindRoot[lhs == rhs, {x, x0, x1}]` searches for a solution using $x_0$ and $x_1$ as the first two values of $x$, avoiding the use of derivatives. ... If you specify two starting values, `FindRoot` uses a variant of the secant method.

Indeed, that does the job pretty much instantly:

```
FindRoot[func[u] - num == 0, {u, -3, 3}]
(* {u -> 0.00249415} *)
```

Comment: I was googling secant before I post this. Somehow I didn't find how to do it in mathematica.... I should have read the doc more carefully. Thank you very much for quick response : )